# Stopping Text to Speech wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, text-to-speech

I am developing a WP8 application and Text to Speech is used heavily in it, In the app when you click on a button to go to a new page it tells which button you have pressed, but I want the text to speech to stop as soon as it changes page, Is there a way of stopping the text to speech as soon as a new page appears, even if the text to speech is only half way through what it has to say. here is a small piece of code from my application so I want to cut off the voice as soon as it goes to the instructions page, any help you be much appreciated. Thanks

```
  private async void SayWords(string words)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

         await synth.SpeakTextAsync(words);

    }

private void Instructions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        checkSender(sender); 
            TapCount++;
        if (TapCount == 2)
        {
              NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/instructions.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

        else
        {
            SayWords("You have selected the Instructions");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `CancelAll` method.

```
private SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    await synth.SpeakTextAsync("You have an incoming notification from Big Bank.");
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
       synth.CancelAll();
}
```

Comment: quick question, im not doing it the way your doing it there I have one method in which all the speech synthesis happens.

   private async void SayWords(string words)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

             await synth.SpeakTextAsync(words);
             
        }

all the speech comes through this method once it a button is selected

Comment: Then you'll have to expose a method (ex. CancelWords()) to cancel the SayWords () call.

Comment: I changed it up above, I dont want to have a button that says cancel as the users are going to be visually impaired, I'm not the best programmer as I am just starting off, this is just a part im stuck on

Comment: I understand, my sample code was just a simple version with buttons.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the bit of help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the standard `SpeechSynthesizer` then just call the `CancelAll` method.